# Rasterio + QGIS - rasterio.drivers() -> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, rasterio

I have been trying to get rasterio working with my QGIS setup so that I can take advantage of the fast raster manipulations.

After a day of installing / uninstalling and then piece by piece searching and getting components installed one by one where needed (From upgrading GDAL, numpy, and a whole slew of other modules which were fighting each other) I manged to get to the point where I could import rasterio without any errors.

However now when I run, the first call in the example causes a Traceback:

```
with rasterio.drivers(CPL_DEBUG=True):
```

creates error =>

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have noticed that other rasterio objects seem fine, but all functions that are in .pyc files have this same issue.

Any help?  - I will continue in the morning, but I was hoping some elves would appear and help solve this one tonight! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AAmes It looks to me that your code is based on out of date examples or docs. Specifically, the rasterio module no longer exports a `drivers()` function. Please see http://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/quickstart.html for Rasterio 1.0 usage examples.

I'm sorry about the difficulty of integrating Rasterio with QGIS. I haven't tried it myself, but being familiar with the problems of distributing Python C extensions, I'm surprised that you got it to work at all. Normally, Rasterio is installed using pip. I'm not sure what would be required to install it for QGIS's embedded Python.

Comment: Thanks for the note  the drivers() function I took directly from the example that I found.  It looks like it was outdated!!  I am now running into a new problem (Which does not have me at a brick wall as I was before.. and I will keep at it!)  I am now seeing this error repeating: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 875, in emit
    self.flush()
  File "C:\QGIS\apps\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 835, in flush
    self.stream.flush()
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Logged from file env.py, line 160

Comment: As a note of installing it with QGIS - I'll claim success once it is working!  I have seen evidence that there are some people out there who have gotten it to work.  Rasterio is a amazingly powerful module which would vastly accelerate the functionality of working on rasters inside of pyQGIS.  I installed everything using the  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ python wheels.  It took some work to get pip up and wheel up and running but systematically going through all of the dependencies with a pip install *dependency* --upgrade seemed to get me a long ways (got me to import XX)

Comment: oh and this is the location of the BAD example!  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rasterio/0.5.1